# azure account not being recognized by visual studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, azure

was trying to follow documentation here to deploy a website
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-aspnet-core-ef-step-05?view=vs-2019

but Microsoft visual studio isn't detecting my azure account?following the instructions from the page i right click on my project in the Solution explorer and went to publish.

This opens up a dialogue asking to create or select existing. I chose create as I have no priors. This then prompted me for an azure account which I already have. I originalyl clicked sign into an existing account and it didn't pick up my azure account even though the email is the same as the one in my azure portal I then clicked create a new account from visual studio and click on free account button  that popped up on the webpage. it then took me to this screen

account token.[image: azure confusion screenshot]

I've tried restarting vs several times to see if it simply wasn't getting the account token properly or something. I've also checked a million times that the email in the top right of my Azure portal is the same email as the one in the top right of my visual studio dialogue. my only hypothetical problem in my mins is maybe my 30 days didn't actually mean a year free subscription and therefore now I have to upgrade to pay as you go. and pay as you go seems to actually mean 30 dollars a month not free until you get a required service as the payment plan seems to imply.

Comment: There is no base charge for Pay-As-You-Go. You only pay for the services you use. If you have services on your account that were created with free credit and convert them, then you would have to pay for those. If you don't want to convert the existing subscription, you could simply create a new one inside your account based on the Pay-As-You-Go model.

Comment: If you have an active subscription on your account- either the demo subscription is still active or you create a new subscription under the Pay-As-You-Go model and still can't publish from Visual Studio I would suggest you file a support ticket. If you don't have a support plan, please send an email to AzCommunity[at]Microsoft[dot]com referencing this thread and I will try to get your account activated for one-time free technical support.

Answer (score 1):

sorry i was confusing cost of use with cost of support. kind of unclear when setting that up. got that problem fixed. also my free trial had expired so i by default need tto use pay as you go, which is still free as long as i don't used payment services, but i should be careful as there no warning when it will charge you and what will start costing something. it would be nice if you could turn warnings of cost on or something.